# Can I carry a gun in a case in Florida while riding a bicycle?

Tags: florida, self-defense, firearms

I am riding an extended bike trip.  I've already been attacked by multiple dogs.  I applied for a concealed carry permit but I don't want to delay my trip in the meantime.  Can I carry in an unlocked case on my bicycle without my license to carry concealed?  Would a bicycle be sufficient to be considered a vehicle?

Comment: The applicable state law is [Chapter 790](http://www.leg.state.fl.us/statutes/index.cfm?App_mode=Display_Statute&URL=0700-0799/0790/0790.html).

Answer (score 2):

A bicycle has the same legal equivalent as a car in Florida.

> 316.2065 Bicycle regulations.— (1) Every person propelling a vehicle by human power has all of the rights and all of the duties applicable
>   to the driver of any other vehicle under this chapter, except as to
>   special regulations in this chapter, and except as to provisions of
>   this chapter which by their nature can have no application.

As such, you likely need to follow the same rules for transporting a firearm;

- Unloaded
- In a container/bag that is closed/sealed

> 790.25 Lawful ownership, possession, and use of firearms and other weapons. ...
>
> (5) POSSESSION IN PRIVATE CONVEYANCE.—Notwithstanding subsection (2),
>   it is lawful and is not a violation of s. 790.01 for a person 18 years
>   of age or older to possess a concealed firearm or other weapon for
>   self-defense or other lawful purpose within the interior of a private
>   conveyance, without a license, if the firearm or other weapon is
>   securely encased or is otherwise not readily accessible for immediate
>   use. Nothing herein contained prohibits the carrying of a legal
>   firearm other than a handgun anywhere in a private conveyance when
>   such firearm is being carried for a lawful use. Nothing herein
>   contained shall be construed to authorize the carrying of a concealed
>   firearm or other weapon on the person. This subsection shall be
>   liberally construed in favor of the lawful use, ownership, and
>   possession of firearms and other weapons, including lawful
>   self-defense as provided in s. 776.012

Comment: FYI only people have legal rights. The relevant laws pertain to *motor* vehicles, so your equal-rights analysis doesn't fly.

Comment: I changed the wording. But the point still stands, in Florida, a bicycle has the same legal standing on a road way as a *motor vehicle*.

Answer (score 1):

Re: `feetwet's` comments: the state laws are in [Chapter 790.](http://www.leg.state.fl.us/statutes/index.cfm?App_mode=Display_Statute&URL=0700-0799/0790/0790.html)

My point - more of a comment than a legal answer, which is covered by reading the state laws above - is that you're *not very smart* to appear to be preparing to shoot a dog that may be endangering you sometime in the future. The legal ramifications of discharging a firearm, killing/injuring a dog and endangering people in the area are greater than the penalties of flaunting CCW laws (esp. if you are a felon); see the same link to Chapter 790 above.

The proof you will need to show that the said dog was sufficiently endangering you in terms of your own injuries or life to shoot it and endanger people in the area will have to be very convincing to a court.

Get a can of pepper spray (again, as per Chapter 790, less than two ounces) and carry it in full view in a holder on the frame of the bike. Much research and statistics show that pepper spray is much more effective in deterring dogs (and people) than bullets from an aiming and accuracy (read success) standpoint. Or carry a home-made spray bottle of ammonia/water; that is very effective and perfectly legal.

Pepper spraying a dog won't get you thrown in jail. Shooting one may. And, aside from all that: knowing the propensity of citizens to carry guns and use them, shooting a dog may encourage someone to shoot back at you.

Comment: You answer the situation and link to where the answer to the questions might be findable, but you don't seem to answer the questions.

Comment: Not a remotely helpful response.  Assuming I am "not very smart" is also rude.  I do not have a particular dog in mind nor would I fire a gun into a busy residential neighborhood.  I am referring to very rural areas where randomly dogs come running out at me.  I carry bear spray as well but in this particular circumstance the dog was 20 yards away chasing after my 6 year old daughter.  I am trained to use my firearm and would not fire it to risk anyone else's life.  I simply was looking for a legal opinion whether a bicycle qualified as a vehicle

Comment: Cade: "I simply was looking for a legal opinion whether a bicycle qualified as a vehicle." OK, simply ask that. Try deleting the line "I've already been attacked by multiple dogs" from your question and see how it reads. My point is that all anyone knows here is _exactly_ what you write; you mention being attacked by dogs and going on a bike trip and wanting to know if you could carry a gun on a bike without waiting for your CWP and if a bike is a vehicle. So what does all that add up to?

Comment: Lots of commentary in this answer are unnecessary in context to the question asked.